# What happens if I never end session in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm curious about what will happen if I don't limit the session time out.

**Will it affect the server?**

is it considered as bad practice? if yes, why?

thank you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a session garbage collector than normally runs periodically and cleans up old sessions. There are `php.ini` parameters that control how old a session has to be deleted.

[How the PHP Session Garbage Collector Really Works](http://www.dev-metal.com/how-the-php-session-garbage-collector-really-works/)

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? or refer me to a link?

Comment: Added a link with an explanation

Comment: I'm using codeigniter (PHP framework) and i have set the session life to indefinite which is "0". My concern is will sessions not explicitly logged out, continue to exist on the server, leading to higher use of server ram.

Comment: Sessions are stored in files, not RAM.

Comment: i see, can you answer all the sub-questions I asked? :)

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274482/codeigniter-questions-native-php-sessions-code-flow-layout-issues?rq=1) says that CodeIgniter has its own sessions, which it stores in its database. It doesn't use PHP sessions by default.

Comment: I don't know anything about CodeIgniter myself, I've never used it. I got that from the **Related** list in the sidebar. There are several good questions there about CI sessions versus PHP sessions.

Comment: is it considered bad practice?

Comment: If you want users to be able to stay logged in for a long time, it's a reasonable thing to do. I don't think it causes any problems for he server, cleaning up sessions is usually a policy decision.

Comment: yeah actually my users want to stay logged in for a really long time.
I just need to make sure that it doesn't affect the performance.

Comment: Disk space is cheap. And unless you have a huge amount of session data, it's not even much disk space. Usually the session just has a handful of variables like the username and some privilege flags.

Comment: yeah i know what session has in it. :)